# Undefined Control Sequence Error with \listofencl and Titlesec

Tags: titlesec, phantom

With `titlesec` loaded, if I replace `\subsection` by `\phantomsection` I get the stated error. With that pkg removed, the replacement compiles fine. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, pdfpages, mwe}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlistof{encl}{encl}{Enclosed}%\listenclname
\newcommand{\encl}[1]
{%
  \refstepcounter{encl}
  \addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\theencl.~#1}
}
\makeatletter
% \@cfthaschapterfalse %Don't need
\def\listofencl{\@cfttocstart\@nameuse{cftmarkencl}\@starttoc{encl}\@cfttocfinish}
\makeatother

% ---
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{rest}%
[\small \normalfont] %]\sffamily]
{%
  \sethead{L}{C}{R}
  \setfoot{foo}{bar}{qux}
}
\pagestyle{rest}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Unwanted Title}
% \phantomsection
\noindent \listofencl % TODO
%\vspace{-1em}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\textbf{Textual}}
\encl{Foo}
\label{encl:transcr}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\textbf{Enclosed}}
\encl{Bar}
\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true]{example-image-a.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Shell:

```
$ tectonic --version
Tectonic 0.14.1
[erwann@elitebook tex]$ tectonic debug-5.tex
Running TeX ...
error: debug-5.tex:29: Undefined control sequence
error: halted on potentially-recoverable error as specified
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: \phantomsection is a hyperref command.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer loading this package last results in the same error.

Comment: it is a bug in titlesec/titleps. Add `\makeatletter\let\ttl@savemark\@empty\makeatother`.

Comment: It seems that tectonic hides the most important information: WHAT control sequence is undefined. TeX reports it in its error message, but I don't se it in your report from tectonic. Why you are using a tool which hides such important information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an incompatibility between `\phantomsection` on the one hand, and `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`+`\pagestyle{<style>}` on the other hand. I've added the `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` statement [suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696627/undefined-control-sequence-error-with-listofencl-and-titlesec?noredirect=1#comment1730206_696627), and the file now compiles fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum, pdfpages, mwe}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newlistof{encl}{encl}{Enclosed}%\listenclname
\newcommand{\encl}[1]
{%
  \refstepcounter{encl}
  \addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\theencl.~#1}
}
\makeatletter
% \@cfthaschapterfalse %Don't need
\def\listofencl{\@cfttocstart\@nameuse{cftmarkencl}\@starttoc{encl}\@cfttocfinish}
\makeatother

% ---
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\newpagestyle{rest}%
[\small \normalfont] %]\sffamily]
{%
  \sethead{L}{C}{R}
  \setfoot{foo}{bar}{qux}
}
\pagestyle{rest}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696627/undefined-control-sequence-error-with-listofencl-and-titlesec?noredirect=1#comment1730206_696627
\makeatletter\let\ttl@savemark\@empty\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\subsection*{Unwanted Title}
\phantomsection
\noindent \listofencl % TODO
%\vspace{-1em}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\textbf{Textual}}
\encl{Foo}
\label{encl:transcr}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\addcontentsline{encl}{encl}{\textbf{Enclosed}}
\encl{Bar}
\includepdf[pages={1},fitpaper=true]{example-image-a.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]